# More Restrictive Child Interfaces

Tags: php, inheritance, interface

I have a particular use-case where I'd like a child interface to have constraints on its return values that the parent interface does not.  So, for example:

```
interface FooInterface
{
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function foo();
}

interface IntegerOnlyFooInterface extends FooInterface
{
    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function foo();
}
```

In this example, the `IntegerOnlyFooInterface` will only return integers for the call to `foo()`.  Because integers are also scalars, this doesn't break the contract inherited from `FooInterface`, and satisfies the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), as `IntegerOnlyFooInterfaces` may be used anywhere that requires a `FooInterface` instance without breaking anything in the application.

There are places where I'd like to enforce the integer return value as part of the code's contract, though, so in those places I would typehint for an `IntegerOnlyFooInterface`.

This seems rather kludgy, though, and I'm wondering if I'm going about the problem the wrong way, or if it's on the up-and-up.